# Error creating setup project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Hello I have created an WinForms Application(.Net Framework 4.8) with ReportViewer. The application is working without any error. Now I tried to create an setup project for the application and I always get the following errors displayed.

> WARNING: Unable to find dependency
> 'MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.SHELL.DESIGN' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A'
> Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll'
> WARNING: Unable to find dependency
> 'MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.SHELL.DESIGN' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A'
> Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll'
> WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.SHELL.14.0'
> (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly
> 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll' WARNING: Unable to find dependency
> 'MICROSOFT.VISUALSTUDIO.SHELL.14.0' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A'
> Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll'
> WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.VSDESIGNER'
> (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly
> 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll' WARNING: Unable to find dependency
> 'MICROSOFT.VSDESIGNER' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A'
> Version='14.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll'

All the dll in the error message are in the bin folder available.

Can anybody help me out here.

**EDIT 07.05.2021**

*Nuget Package for Report:*
Corrected.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Corrected.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/150.1358.0?_src=template

*Steps to Create a SETUP:*

- Load Extension 'Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project
- Right Click on my Solution -> ADD -> Create NEW PROJECT
- Choose SETUP Project
- In FileSystem Folder Application Folder -> Right Click -> ADD -> Project Output
- Choose Primary output
- ADD in Folder User's Desktop -> Shortcut from Primary output
  (Shortcut created in Applicatin Folder by rightclicking on Primary
  output)
- ADD in Folder User's Programs Menu -> Shortcut from Primary output
  (Shortcut created in Applicatin Folder by rightclicking on Primary
  output)
- Rebuild SETUP Project

After these steps the above error occurres.
The application itself is working without any error.

Comment: Hi, @ SaMat.
Have you downloaded and used  **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms**?  Do you add 
 ReportViewer to Toolbox like the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15#add-the-control-to-visual-studio-toolbar)? What kind of data source do you create for Report before using ReportViewer? What are your steps to create a setup project? Please provide me more details and related steps to reproduce and analyze the issue.

Comment: @ Hui Liu -MFST. I edit my question. Thanks